# D3.js - accessing data in nested array

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a data array that looks like this:

```
    var data = [
  {
    "key": "user",
    "values": [
      "roles",
      "manager",
      "otherRoles",
      "reports",
      "devices",
      "coffees"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "role",
    "values": [
      "assignments",
      "members",
      "otherMembers"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "assignment",
    "values": [
      "roles"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Device",
    "values": [
      "owners",
      "roles"
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Coffee",
    "values": [
      "drinkers"
    ]
  }
];
```

I am attempting to render tables from SVG rectangles where the table header is the "key" and the table rows are the "values".  The only way I was able to make this work was to give a unique incremental class to each table (table0, table1 etc.)  I know this is terrible and prevents me from easily accessing all tables in the future.  Here is the pertinent code:

```
                parentBox = svgContainer.selectAll('.table')
                    .data(data, function(d) {return d.key;})
                    .enter()
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('class', function(d, i) {
                        return "table" + i;
                    })
                    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                        return "translate(" + boxWidth*i + "," + rowHeight*i + ")"; 
                    });
```

I'd like to figure out the right way to access nested data in D3.  Here is the code in its entirety: [D3 Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Dadsaster/ps04w6g6/4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the solution just requires understanding selections better.  I first created the parentBox container:

```
parentBox = svgContainer.selectAll('.table')
   .data(data, function(d) {return d.key;})
   .enter()
   .append('g')
   .attr('class', 'table') (etc.)
```

Then, when populating the table with rows I first selected the created tables, used the each method to loop through each table and create each row.  The one trick was to use `d3.select(this)` to make sure the rows were created properly.

```
             svgContainer.selectAll('.table')
                .each(function (d, i) {
                    tableRows = d3.select(this).selectAll('.row')
                        .data(d.values)
                        .enter()
                        .append(g) (etc.)
```